# Designing an AI for isometric tilemap game

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I had more of a design question then programming specifically.  Basically I am working on an isometric tyle-map style game using cocos2d (soon to be migrated to sprite kit) and I'm trying to figure out some best practices for implementing the AI for enemy sprites.

This is the basic logic I have:

-Enemy determines location of player and angle at which player is at
-Enemy will then move a single tile based off this angle (ie left,right,up,down,upleft, etc...)
-Enemy will animate with a ccaction showing them moving in that direction
-If distance of player and enemy is less then X then enemy will fire at player
-If distance of player and enemy is less then Y then enemy will move in opposite tile direction from moving towards player
-If enemy detects that future tile move is a collision, enemy will not move

It's a very basic logic and I am running into 2 problems:
-When the enemy detects a collision, it will stop moving entirely
-At certain angles that the player is at between the enemy, the sprite image will flicker back and forth between the 2 different bordering angles
-Because I have many sprites spawning at one point they all are moving in the same direction and completely overlap, I want to try and spread them apart without having tons of spawn points on the map (so far there are 5 spawn points, each spawning about 4-5 enemies)

I wanted to see if anyone out there has any good pointers on how to make this more sophisticated where I can potentially avoid these problems and develop more "intelligence" to the enemy sprites.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different algorithms for AI pathfinding. One that I particularly like is called A* (A Star) and works very well on 2-D grids with horizontal and diagonal movement, and should meet your requirements with minor tweaking.

Here is the wikipedia page which has a good amount of information about A*:

[A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

Comment: I also recommend this page to try out the different pathfinding algorithms: http://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

Comment: I think I understand it at this point reading the wiki.  The only thing I'm wondering is if the heuristic is necessary?  I guess in my case the way it would work is I would pass the destination tile position and origin tile position

Comment: The heuristic is used at each point along the path, not just at the start and finish. It allows it to calculate the fastest path quickly.

Comment: I guess in my case the way it would work is I would pass the destination tile position and origin tile position.  Each neighboring tile would have a distance value of 1.  I would also have to check if a tile position is blocked/collision and skip that tile position.  
Basically I would go through as the pseudo code shows until i reach the destination tile position.  I guess I would thee return some array structure containing the path for the sprite to follow.